# I want to bind a list to my combo box but it only shows collection in the dropdown

Tags: c#, binding

```
comboBox1.Items.Add(langerlist);
//for information's sake, the list is called langerlist
```

Comment: Without more codes, it is impossible to find the problem. What is langerlist ?

Answer (score 1):

Add only adds one item you need to use AddRange

```
comboBox1.Items.AddRange(langerlist.ToArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the property that you want to display using `DisplayMember`:

```
comboBox1.Items.AddRange(langerlist.ToArray());
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
comboBox1.ValueMember = "ID";


public class MyClass
{
    public string Name { set; get; }
    public string ID { set; get; }
}
```